# Auto rotate screen on Dell 13 7000 with 15.04 (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, 15.04, touchscreen, rotate

Gnome seems very suited for touch enabled devices, is there a way to auto rotate the screen when I flip the laptop/tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This software](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy) was reported to work on many 2-in-1 devices. But you have to run the latest kernel and gnome.

Comment: I'll check it out

Answer (score 4):

Edit: I know this doesn't answer your question directly since we have different computers and you are interested in Gnome, but I wanted to post this somewhere to help others.

The following worked for me for Ubuntu 16.10 (Unity) on a Spectre x360 (Kaby Lake). I suspect a similar treatment should work for other laptops.

As in @Yalokly's answer, install `iio-sensor-proxy`:

```
sudo apt-get install iio-sensor-proxy
```

This can be a can of worms to get working. You know it's working if when you run `monitor-sensor` stuff happens when you rotate your device. [Here](https://github.com/hadess/iio-sensor-proxy) is the repo where you might find some troubleshooting info. I had some trouble getting it going. Updating my kernel from 4.8 to 4.10 worked for me. Search for a tutorial online. Like many others, I have the bug where sensor monitoring only works after the computer has been suspended-resumed at least once.

Unity does not do auto-rotation and tablet mode stuff on its own. I combined scripts from [here](https://linuxappfinder.com/blog/auto_screen_rotation_in_ubuntu) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757900/hp-spectre-x360-disable-touchpad-in-tablet-mode-ubuntu-15-10) so that:

1. Screen rotates automatically
2. Keyboard and trackpad only work when laptop is normally oriented; disabled in the other three orientations
3. Unity launcher is placed at the bottom for portrait orientations, and left for landscape orientations
4. The `onboard` program is started in the three 'tablet' orientations and killed for the 'laptop' orientation (extra: I found it helpful to enable auto-popup in text mode in the onboard preferences)

Here is the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
# IH: this script is taken from a combo of:
# https://linuxappfinder.com/blog/auto_screen_rotation_in_ubuntu
# https://askubuntu.com/questions/757900/hp-spectre-x360-disable-touchpad-in-tablet-mode-ubuntu-15-10

# Auto rotate screen based on device orientation

# Receives input from monitor-sensor (part of iio-sensor-proxy package)
# Screen orientation and launcher location is set based upon accelerometer position
# Launcher will be on the left in a landscape orientation and on the bottom in a portrait orientation
# This script should be added to startup applications for the user

# Clear sensor.log so it doesn't get too long over time
> sensor.log

# Launch monitor-sensor and store the output in a variable that can be parsed by the rest of the script
monitor-sensor >> sensor.log 2>&1 &

# Parse output or monitor sensor to get the new orientation whenever the log file is updated
# Possibles are: normal, bottom-up, right-up, left-up
# Light data will be ignored
while inotifywait -e modify sensor.log; do
# Read the last line that was added to the file and get the orientation
ORIENTATION=$(tail -n 1 sensor.log | grep 'orientation' | grep -oE '[^ ]+$')

# Set the actions to be taken for each possible orientation
case "$ORIENTATION" in
normal)
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate normal
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left 
    xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 1 #Enable Keyboard
    xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 1 #Enable Pad
    killall onboard
    ;;
bottom-up)
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate inverted
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Left 
    xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Keyboard
    xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Pad
    onboard &
    ;;
right-up)
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate right
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
    xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Keyboard
    xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Pad
    onboard &
    ;;
left-up)
    xrandr --output eDP-1 --rotate left
    gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
    xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Keyboard
    xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Pad
    onboard &
    ;;
esac
done
```

Note: My screen is called `eDP-1`, yours may be called something different. Run `xrandr` to find out the name, and change the four instances in the above script.

Save this somewhere as `auto-rotate.sh`, make it executable (`chmod a+x auto-rotate.sh`), and add it to *Startup Applications*.

Answer (score 0):

I have used @Ian Hincks code, but I have a little suggestion for do it useful.
I have a Dell Inspiron 13 7000 series, and this machine has a Light sensor to balance the backlight bright. I had to modify the build of "orientation" line, because the light sensor changes are quicks and contaminates the orientation captured. Then I receive three light changes,by one line of orientation. If I capture only one line of the log, I loose the orientation line. 
This is why I have increased the log capture to 4 lines, and changed the grep regex to capture last orientation. Then, the new ORIENTATION line will be:

```
ORIENTATION=$(tail -n 4 sensor.log | grep 'orientation' | grep -oEm 1 '[^ ]+$')
```

Thank you @Ian Hincks for your code!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [autorotate](https://github.com/undg/autorotate)

It can rotate the screen and digitizer manually or automatically. There is an option for systemd daemon to run it in background.