# HP Spectre x360 Disable Touchpad in Tablet Mode - Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, touchpad, tablet, mode, onscreen-keyboard

so I got ubuntu installed and figured out the sound issue and a few other problems but when I rotate my screen to the back so the laptop is in tablet mode, the touchpad is still active. Ubuntu disables the keys automatically (I think this happened when I upgraded to 15.10), but it doesn't disable the mousepad. I also don't get an onscreen keyboard when in tablet mode.

I tried looking it up but everything I found was for other laptops (mostly Lenovo and Dell models) and I couldn't understand the acpi stuff well enough to figure out how to get it to work for mine. Does anyone have any suggestions? I know how to manually disable the touchpad and enable the onscreen keyboard from the command line, but I want it to happen automatically when I rotate the screen to the back.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally there is an event that we can respond to and have this happen automatically, but it looks like this is still an open issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/1535008
Also see: https://askubuntu.com/a/732830/519324

So I'm going to combine the following answers:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/766150/519324
- https://askubuntu.com/a/485685/519324

**1. Find keyboard & trackpad IDs**
Find the IDs for your keyboard/trackpad or what ever you want to disable using the following command. Mine is 12 for keyboard and 13 for Touchpad. Write it down.

```
xinput list
```

**2. Find your display ID**

Run the followiing command to find the connected screen, it's the ID that's followed by "connected". Mine is "eDP1".

```
xrandr
```

**3. Write tablet mode script**

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/tablet-mode.sh
```

Fill with the following script. Change 12 and 13 to your keyboard/trackpad IDs and change eDP1 to your display ID.

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Keyboard
xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Pad
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate inverted #Rotate screen
onboard & #Turn on onscreen keyboard
```

Give it executable rights:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/tablet-mode.sh
```

**4. Write laptop mode script**

```
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/laptop-mode.sh
```

Fill with:

```
#!/bin/bash
xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 1 #Enable Keyboard
xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 1 #Enable Pad
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal #Rotate screen back
killall onboard #Turn off onscreen keyboard
```

Give it executable rights:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/laptop-mode.sh
```

**5. Create tablet mode icon**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/tablet-mode.desktop
```

Fill with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Tablet Mode
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/media-playback-stop.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/tablet-mode.sh
```

**6. Create laptop mode icon**

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/laptop-mode.desktop
```

Fill with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Laptop Mode
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/media-playback-stop.png
Exec=/usr/local/bin/laptop-mode.sh
```

You probably need to re-login to get the icons.

Comment: This works on Ubuntu 16.10 too. I use `/usr/share/icons/suru/devices/scalable/{computer-laptop,input-tablet}-symbolic.svg` for icons. Nice hack! +1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Pavilion X360 so here is what I did for a work around to disable the keyboard and pad and to rotate my screen so I can use it as a tablet. This might work for you.

First I created a icon.

sudo vim /usr/share/applications/Keyboard-OFF.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Tablet Mode
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/media-playback-stop.png
Exec=/bin/KeyboardOff.sh
```

Feel Free to change the icon I used pause stop left and right so I can rotate my screen in different directions and pinned them to the bar.

Then

```
xinput list
```

Find your the ID for your keyboard/trackpad or what ever you want to disable
Note it down.
Mine is 12 for keyboard and 13 for Touchpad

for display run

```
xrandr
```

find your display mine is eDP1

then

sudo vim /bin/KeyboardOff.sh

Change 12 and 13 to your ID
Change eDP1 to your display

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "EnterPasswordHere" | sudo -S xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Keyboard
echo "EnterPasswordHere" | sudo -S xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 0 #Disable Pad
echo "EnterPasswordHEre" | sudo -S xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate inverted
onboard & #Turn on onscreen keyboard
echo ""
echo "Keyboard is off"
```

Then create and pin another to turn it back on

sudo vim /usr/share/applications/Keyboard-ON.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=Laptop Mode On
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/actions/media-playback-pause.png
Exec=/bin/KeyboardOn.sh
```

sudo vim /bin/KeyboardOn.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "YourPasswordHere" | sudo -S xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 1
echo "YourPasswordHere" | sudo -S xinput set-int-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 8 1
echo "YourPasswordHere" | sudo -S xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal
echo ""
echo "Keyboard is back on"
exit
```

Remember to change 12 and 13 and eDP1 to your keyboard/pad & display the 0 or 1 at the end turns it on and off you can also create more icons to rotate left and right by changing  --rotate normal to --rotate right or left

I know this does not answer your question specifically but I found being able to select these rather than going to tablet mode seems to be easier as tablet mode seems to be a bit unstable as of now.

Hope this helps you or anyone else running into this. Sorry for the response being a bit crude.

Comment: I tried the command `xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate inverted` and the screen did invert but the touch went crazy, even after I did `xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate normal`.Do you know a fix?