# HP Spectre X360 trackpad screen

Tags: 16.04, touchscreen

Everything works great after installation of 16.04 except when I close the screen and reopen it later I find multiple applications have been opened all over the screen.  Also the keyboard does not turn off in tablet mode.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and was going to write a script using something like below. However I upgraded to 16.10 daily and seems to work now.

But I was going to do something like

```
while true; do cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state ; sleep 3; done
```

and `grep` for "open" or "closed".

then have that run

```
echo "password" | sudo -S xinput set-int-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 8 1
```

or you can run `pm-hibernate`

When I break down and do it I will post it unless someone out there want to slap something together.

Check out this link it might help

[HP Spectre x360 Disable Touchpad in Tablet Mode - Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757900/hp-spectre-x360-disable-touchpad-in-tablet-mode-ubuntu-15-10)