# How to enable screen auto rotation on Dell 5378 2 in 1?

Tags: touchscreen, display-rotation

I bought a new laptop, 2 in 1 Dell 13" 5378 and would like to use it as a tablet from time to time. The problem is that the screen won't flip when in tablet mode and onscreen keyboard won't open up automatically  when I open a browser. It will open with Libre office and some other text editing programs.
I have tried some options to install:

apt install iio-sensor-proxy inotify-tools

but so far unlucky. The screen has to be turned,flipped manually. The touchpad and physical keyboard is disabled in tablet mode and touchscreen works normally.
Anyone with a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: please visit https://askubuntu.com/questions/634151/auto-rotate-screen-on-dell-13-7000-with-15-04-gnome/937321#937321, it was useful for me.